# Can I replace a single breaker with a double in the space above where broken tab is

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I have a broken tab on a panel board. Can I replace a single with a double breaker?

[image: panel board]

Comment: It appears you have a damaged rail where the breaker clips on. It is not entirely clear why you want to replace the single with the double but I presume it is to power two separate circuits with one breaker. Have you looked for replacement parts for your panel? Replacing the "guts" of the panel would return it to full functionality.

Comment: What amp rating was the breaker that went into the damaged slot?  (Also, that panel's looking rather crusty, sadly...shame to see this happen to a good QO box)

Comment: I had an older CH panel that looked worse.  I was able to de-energize it (to be more precise thanks to copper theft energizing it was an *odyssey*.)  i cleaned it thoroughly, it cleaned up very nicely.  Given this one's damage and small size, I would swap the panel for at least a 24.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a few things to consider. First a QO double pole breaker usually has only one connection point to the tabs. So make sure it's on the correct side.

Second, and I know this might be nitpicking but NEC Article 110.12(B) Integrity of Electrical Equipment and Connections states *there shall be no damaged parts that may adversely affect the safe operation or mechanical strength of the equipment such as parts that are broken; bent; cut; or deteriorated by corrosion, chemical action, or overheating.*

So the question is: Does that fit this situation? Which I cannot answer because I am not there. What I will tell you that is I if I were still running a service company, I would have a liability to my customer and my state license. I would replace it.

I am not sure of the age of the panel but you might be able to find a comparable box where the guts match and just replace the guts rather than the whole panel.

Whatever you decide use good judgement and be safe.

Answer (score 0):

The question "can I...?" has 2 parts. "Am I allowed to locate breakers in a box in certain way?" is one question. "Am I allowed to use a load center that contains defective parts if I avoid using any of the defective parts?" is the other question.

The work-around is proposed to avoid using a breaker space in imperfect condition. A previous answer quoted the NEC to the effect that equipment in an imperfect condition must not be used if it adversely affects safe operation. If the imperfection in the breaker space has no effect on safe operation when the space isn't used, then when the load center is configured for safe operation the quoted provision of the NEC wouldn't explicitly prohibit using the load center, even though some other configurations for which the load center is listed would be unsafe. The NEC and the statutory laws invoking it also have more general good workmanship provisions that would be interpreted as prohibiting this use. In general terms, a good workman doesn't intentionally use defective components, so the work to be performed can't leave the broken breaker space grab bar as it is.

The load center's internal assembly is the field-replaceable unit that includes the broken part. If the case is in good condition replacing just the internal assembly can avoid un-needed work. It isn't clear if the brown areas at the bottom of the cabinet near the power feeders are rust, kraft paper, or dust and dirt. If corroded the case has to be replaced. Frequently it's more cost effective to purchase a load center w/o a main breaker to obtain the internal assembly.

There is a second, unrelated, unsafe non-conformity that must also be corrected. Two single pole breakers have their handles pinned together (by a box nail?) to imitate a two pole breaker with a common trip. That's not really exotic, but it isn't allowed by the NEC because it doesn't always work - sometimes the pole that has tripped trip moves it's handle to the tripped position (midway) but that isn't far enough to manually open the other breaker, and the circuit remains connected to one phase.

The condition of the branch circuit breakers can't be accurately determined from the photo, but if the corrosion suggested by the images is present, or the plastic cases are as deteriorated as they appear then they also require replacement.

The breaker cover would have needed blanks to fill any previously used spaces now unfilled, but either replacing the load center or harvesting a replacement assembly from a new load center will make a new breaker cover 
available to use instead.

Comment: While the nail *is* an improper handle tie, two-pole independent trip breakers (or two handle tied single pole breakers) *are* allowed by the NEC for a 240V circuit if it is feeding a single load, 240V-only loads, or 120V-only loads.